# Create table query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, ms-access-2013

I am simply trying to make a table. The code I have is:

```
{
    Connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand();
    Command.Connection = Connection;

    Command.CommandText = @"CREATE TABLE Login
    (
       Login_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
       ID int  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Stud_Rec(ID)
    )";

    Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Connection.Close();
}
```

I get the following error:

> Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause

I believe my syntax should be all correct, and don't know what's wrong with my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Login
(
     Login_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     ID int,
     FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Stud_Rec(ID)
)
```

You missed a comma before `foreign` and did not name the foreign key.

If you use a SQL tool to highlight the errors in your SQL code you find it way easier.

Comment: stud_rec_key is not Defined...But I have Solved My Problem As

Comment: CREATE TABLE Login
(
     Login_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     ID int,
     FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Stud_Rec(ID)
)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it as;

```sql
CREATE TABLE Login
(
     Login_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     ID int,
     FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES Stud_Rec(ID)
)
```

Comment: That's exactly juergen's answer!

Comment: He has edited his answer ...The Initial answer was not this one.